# Control de versiones GIT, desapareció mi solución VS19

Tags: git, github

me pareció que necesitaba investigar sobre GIT para, justamente, evitar perder mi proyecto. Cuestión que, creo el repositorio en GITHUB a través de Visual Studio 19; se vió reflejado el directorio en el sitio, pero sólo se publicaron 2 archivos (.gitattributes y .gitignore). Mucho no le di importancia. Seguí investigando, y en algún momento apreté un botón que decía "guardar provisionalmente", supuse guardaría mi proyecto. Pero borró todo, sólo quedó el directorio y algunos archivos que no son útiles para recuperar mi solución. Por supuesto, el repositorio no está publicado en github, ¿qué hago?

Comment: Guardar provisionalmente suena que hiciste un Stash... Ve a la pestaña de Git Changes (Mi VS está en inglés), y mira si tienes algún cambio provisional/stash en la ventana.

Comment: No tengo stashes, ahora entiendo que también apreté "quitar todo" de la ventana Stashes. ¿puedo recuperarlo?

Comment: Como sabes que no tienes stashes? Podrias colocar la salida (como texto) de esta comando como parte de la pregunta? `git stash list`.

Comment: stash@{0}: WIP on master: 31ae352